Kernel 6.8 shows symbolic links as?
is there a known issue with kernel 6.8 not handling symbolic links correctly? I created a brand new Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4 virtual machine which defaulted to using kernel 6.8 and I see symbolic links as shown in the screenshot below. If I reboot and use kernel 5.15 the symbolic links display correctly. The symbolic links are from a CIFS mount created using PAM. As an interesting note, I can access the same symbolic links OK using the SMB protocol on kernel 6.8.

$ ls -la
ls: cannot access 'AGTC Technical': Operation not supported 
ls: cannot access 'BIOTECH': Operation not supported
ls: cannot access 'Independent': Operation not supported
ls: cannot access 'MaP': Operation not supported
ls: cannot access 'PLANTS: Operation not supported
ls: cannot access 'VIROLOGY: Operation not supported
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 gourled-adx gourled-adx    0 May 28 12:09
drwxr-xr-x 2 gourled-adx gourled-adxn   0 Aug 27 15:54
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ? 'AGTC Technical'
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ?  BIOTECH
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gourled-adx gourled-adx 8196 Apr 29 15:35  .DS_Store
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ?  Independent
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ?  MaP
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ?  PLANTS
d????????? ?             ?              ?            ?  VIROLOGY


Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format. What are the mount options being applied to this CIFS mount?

Hi muru, here are the two configuration files used:

cat ~/.pam_mount.conf.xml

<pam_mount>


</pam_mount>

cat /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml


<pam_mount>






</pam_mount>
